# CloudFormation stuck on Service creation. When checking resources, task definition is created however task hasn't kicked-in

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

So I have an issue I encountered when trying to deploy a stack in CloudFormation for ECS and supporting resources.
The event viewer is showing all resources were created + I can see them fine in the console (even the Service with the task definition)
However, the Service resource is not finalizing the its creation and its timeout after a long time with not failure information / exception I can learn from.
Anyone have any idea why the Service is not finalizing? Is it due to the task not starting from the container?
I added my CFN template below.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

[CFN event viewer][1]

````
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Description: Creating ECS cluster for cloudformation test
Parameters: 
    InstanceType:
        Description: WebServer EC2 instance type (has default, AllowedValues)
        Type: String
        Default: t3.micro
        AllowedValues:
            - t1.micro
            - t2.nano
            - t2.micro
            - t2.small
            - t3.micro
        ConstraintDescription: must be a valid EC2 instance type.
    VpcId:
        Type: String
        Default: 
        Description: Galooli VPC ID
    EnvironmentName:
        Type: String
        Default: Staging
        Description: Env for deployment
    ServiceName:
        Type: String
        Default: SrvCoreOps-POC
        Description: A name for the service   
    ClusterName:
        Type: String
        Default: cluster-staging-internal-poc
        Description: A name for the Cluster
    ImageUrl:
        Type: String
        Default: ${AWS::AccountId}.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/staging/services_core/srvcoreopsinternal_poc:latest
        Description: The url of a docker image that contains the application process that
                    will handle the traffic for this service
    ContainerPort:
        Type: Number
        Default: 87
        Description: What port number the application inside the docker container is binding to
    ContainerCpu:
        Type: Number
        Default: 1024
        Description: How much CPU to give the container. 1024 is 1 CPU
    ContainerMemory:
        Type: Number
        Default: 512
        Description: How much memory in megabytes to give the container
    Path:
        Type: String
        Default: "*"
        Description: A path on the public load balancer that this service
                    should be connected to. Use * to send all load balancer
                    traffic to this service.
    Priority:
        Type: Number
        Default: 1
        Description: The priority for the routing rule added to the load balancer.
                    This only applies if your have multiple services which have been
                    assigned to different paths on the load balancer.
    DesiredCount:
        Type: Number
        Default: 2
        Description: How many copies of the service task to run
    Role:
        Type: String
        Default: arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:role/aws-service-role/ecs.amazonaws.com/AWSServiceRoleForECS
        Description: (Optional) An IAM role to give the service's containers if the code within needs to
                    access other AWS resources like S3 buckets, DynamoDB tables, etc

Resources:
    Cluster:
      Type: "AWS::ECS::Cluster"
      Properties:
          ClusterName: !Ref 'ClusterName'

    TaskDefinition:
        Type: "AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition"
        Properties:
            Family: !Ref 'ServiceName'
            Cpu: !Ref 'ContainerCpu'
            Memory: !Ref 'ContainerMemory'
            ContainerDefinitions:
                - 
                  Name: !Ref 'ServiceName'
                  Cpu: !Ref 'ContainerCpu'
                  Memory: !Ref 'ContainerMemory'
                  Image: !Ref 'ImageUrl'
                  PortMappings:
                    - 
                        ContainerPort: !Ref 'ContainerPort'
                        HostPort: 87
                        Protocol: tcp 
                  WorkingDirectory: "/app"
            RequiresCompatibilities:
                    - "EC2"
            TaskRoleArn: !Sub arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:role/role.iam.galooli.ecs.task


    EC2Instacne:
        Type: "AWS::EC2::Instance"
        Properties:
            ImageId: "ami-098616968d61e549e"
            InstanceType: !Ref InstanceType
            KeyName: "galooli.virginia"
            AvailabilityZone: !Sub "${AWS::Region}c"
            Tenancy: "default"
            SubnetId: "subnet-3"
            EbsOptimized: false
            SourceDestCheck: true
            BlockDeviceMappings: 
              - 
                DeviceName: "/dev/xvda"
                Ebs: 
                    Encrypted: false
                    VolumeSize: 100
                    SnapshotId: "snap-06653072c5ed09151"
                    VolumeType: "gp2"
                    DeleteOnTermination: true
            UserData: "IyEvYmluL2Jhc2gKZWNobyBFQ1NfQ0xVU1RFUj1jbHVzdGVyLXN0YWdpbmctaW50ZXJuYWwgPj4gL2V0Yy9lY3MvZWNzLmNvbmZpZztlY2hvIEVDU19CQUNLRU5EX0hPU1Q9ID4+IC9ldGMvZWNzL2Vjcy5jb25maWc7"
            IamInstanceProfile: "role.iam.galooli.ec2"
            Monitoring: true
            HibernationOptions: 
                Configured: false
            CpuOptions: 
                CoreCount: 1
                ThreadsPerCore: 2
            EnclaveOptions: 
                Enabled: false
    TargetGroup:
        Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup
        Properties:
            HealthCheckIntervalSeconds: 6
            HealthCheckPath: /
            HealthCheckProtocol: HTTP
            HealthCheckTimeoutSeconds: 5
            HealthyThresholdCount: 2
            Name: !Ref 'ServiceName'
            Port: 80
            Protocol: HTTP
            UnhealthyThresholdCount: 2
            VpcId:
                !Ref 'VpcId'

    MyAWSElasticLoadBalancingV2LoadBalancer:
        Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::LoadBalancer
        Properties:
            IpAddressType: ipv4
            SecurityGroups:
                - "sg-0"
            LoadBalancerAttributes:
                - 
                    Key: "access_logs.s3.enabled"
                    Value: "false"
                - 
                    Key: "idle_timeout.timeout_seconds"
                    Value: "60"
                - 
                    Key: "deletion_protection.enabled"
                    Value: "false"
                - 
                    Key: "routing.http2.enabled"
                    Value: "true"
                - 
                    Key: "routing.http.drop_invalid_header_fields.enabled"
                    Value: "false"
                - 
                    Key: "routing.http.xff_client_port.enabled"
                    Value: "false"
                - 
                    Key: "routing.http.desync_mitigation_mode"
                    Value: "defensive"
                - 
                    Key: "waf.fail_open.enabled"
                    Value: "false"
                - 
                    Key: "routing.http.x_amzn_tls_version_and_cipher_suite.enabled"
                    Value: "false"
            Scheme: internal
            Name: !Ref ServiceName
            Subnets:
                - "subnet-3"
                - "subnet-f"
            Type: application


    
    HTTPlistener:
        Type: "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener"
        Properties:
            DefaultActions:
            -   Type: "redirect"
                RedirectConfig:
                    Protocol: "HTTPS"
                    Port: 443
                    Host: "#{host}"
                    Path: "/#{path}"
                    Query: "#{query}"
                    StatusCode: "HTTP_301"                    
            LoadBalancerArn: !Sub arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:loadbalancer/app/load-stg-internal/2fc3d8ed7da577b3
            Port: 81
            Protocol: "HTTP"

    MyAWSLogsLogGroup:
        Type: AWS::Logs::LogGroup
        Properties:
            LogGroupName: !Ref ServiceName
            RetentionInDays: 1
 

    LoadBalancerRule:
        Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::ListenerRule
        Properties:
            Actions:
                - TargetGroupArn: !Ref 'TargetGroup'
                  Type: 'forward'
            Conditions:
                - Field: path-pattern
                  Values: [!Ref 'Path']
            ListenerArn:
                 !Ref HTTPlistener
            Priority: !Ref 'Priority'

    Service:
        Type: "AWS::ECS::Service"
        DependsOn: 
            - HTTPlistener
        DependsOn:
            - MyAWSElasticLoadBalancingV2LoadBalancer
        Properties:
            ServiceName: !Ref 'ServiceName'
            Cluster: !Ref 'ClusterName'
            TaskDefinition: !Ref 'TaskDefinition'
            DesiredCount: !Ref 'DesiredCount'
            LaunchType: "EC2"
            DeploymentConfiguration: 
                MaximumPercent: 200
                MinimumHealthyPercent: 0
                DeploymentCircuitBreaker: 
                    Enable: false
                    Rollback: false
            PlacementStrategies: 
                - 
                    Type: "spread"
                    Field: "attribute:ecs.availability-zone"
                - 
                    Type: "spread"
                    Field: "instanceId"
            SchedulingStrategy: "REPLICA"
            LoadBalancers:
              - ContainerName: !Ref 'ServiceName'
                ContainerPort: !Ref 'ContainerPort'
                TargetGroupArn: !Ref 'TargetGroup'
            Role: !Sub "arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:role/aws-service-role/ecs.amazonaws.com/AWSServiceRoleForECS"


Outputs:
  EnvironmentName:
    Value: !Ref 'EnvironmentName'
  Service:
    Value: !Ref 'ServiceName'
  Cluster:
    Value: !Ref 'ClusterName'
  TaskDefinition:
    Value: !Ref 'TaskDefinition'
  MyAWSLogsLogGroup:
    Value: !GetAtt MyAWSLogsLogGroup.LogGroupName
    Export: 
        Name: MyAWSLogsLogGroup

```YAML


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FAFAX.png
````

Comment: which resource exactly timeouts?

Comment: Also what `Default: ${AWS::AccountId}.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/staging/services_core/srvcoreopsinternal_poc:latest` do you hope to achieve by that?

Comment: The logical ID of the resource that is timing-out is the Service in the ECS =  arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:AccountID:service/cluster-staging-internal-poc/SrvCoreOps-POC. The ECR path is to the container where the application image is located.

Comment: `${AWS::AccountId}.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/staging/services_core/srvcoreopsinternal_poc:latest` is incorrect path. What are values of all the parameters that you pas the the template?

Comment: Thanks for the reply - According to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definition_parameters.html the image parameters path should look like this - Images in Amazon ECR repositories can be specified by using either the full registry/repository:tag or registry/repository@digest naming convention (for example, aws_account_id.dkr.ecr.region.amazonaws.com/my-web-app:latest. What issue do you see? All the values are in the template aside from the AccountId and VPC ID.

Comment: BTW - I've added an image to main post of the event viewer in CFN - Maybe you can learn something from there.

Comment: @Marcin - I changed the image patch to Image@Digest and I ran the stack again - Still stuck on Service CREATE_IN_PROGRESS. Any other ideas or data that I can provide that might be helpful?